# ion-fab not working. I use this upper code but when I run it it showing some small rectangular box

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-fab top right edge>
    <button ion-fab> 
        <ion-icon name="information-circle"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-fab-list>
        <button ion-fab>
            <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button ion-fab>
            <ion-icon name="logo-youtube"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button ion-fab>
            <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
```

ion-fab not working. I use this upper code but when I run it it showing some small rectangular box.

Comment: Add all HTML code and screenshot of output.

Comment: you are in ionic 1 then you have to use action button

Comment: Put all the markup for ion-fab inside an ion-footer block